# Virtual filesystem mapping to local file

Tags: java, filesystems, remote-access

How can I decorate some remote filesystem like a path to directory in java?
For example something like this:

```
File decoratorFileSystem = new File("ftp://host/path"); // this does not work of course
...
File file1 = new File(decoratorFileSystem, "somefile1");
File file2 = new File(decoratorFileSystem, "somefile2");
```

So when I will use `file1`, `file2` or others decorated files I get access to remote file from the decorated filesystem as if it local file with corresponded restrictions.

I think to use virtual file system from "org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider...." but I am not sure is this right way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `File` in Java can only ever reference a real file on a filesystem mounted by the OS (i.e. something that the OS knows to be a file).

Virtual filesystems can't be accessed this way (unless it's handled by the OS, i.e. if you mount a FTP directory directly under Linux, you can use a `File`).

The [newer `Path` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) from NIO2 (available in Java 7 and later) however was explicitly designed with virtual file systems in mind.

Look at [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/filesystemprovider.html) and [the `FileSystemProvider` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/spi/FileSystemProvider.html) to find out how to define your own virtual file system. The [Zip File System Provider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html) is a sample implementation.